# Passing Data In Laravel With Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

We have a backend for our business written in good old PHP, we are now wanting to try to redo it in Laravel but are having problems making the jump.

I have read tons of tutorials but seem to be having trouble finding one that relates. We have a database full of records and for the first page we just want to print them all out into a table.

In regular php we just run a query, put that into an array and parse out the data. I tried doing that in the view controller but am having little success...

The table format may be slightly off just trying to get the data printed for now, also routes and everything work.

I am not 100% on if everything is set up in the ideal place or if this is the ideal way to do it but here is what we have:

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
// Model:'PaymentInfo' - Database Table: 'payment_info'

Class PaymentInfo extends Eloquent
{

    public $connection = 'main';

    protected $table = 'payment_info';

    protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';

    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function getBuyerEmail()
    {
        return $this->buyer_email;
    }

    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }


    public function getMcGross()
    {
        return $this->mc_gross;
    }
```

Then the Controller:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('admin.index');
    }

}
```

Finally the view:

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

<div class="span 8 well">

    <h4>Hello {{ (Auth::user()->username) }}</h4>

</div>

<div>
    <div style="font-size:medium">
    <h1>
    <center>Recent Orders</center>
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="highstyle1">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
    <th>Order #</th>
    <th>Buyer Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Payment</th>
    <th>Buyer Memo</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Transaction ID</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    {{ $order_id = PaymentInfo::all() }}

    @foreach ($order_id as $order)
        <td>{{ PaymentInfo::$order->lastname }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>

@stop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from your view, because it doesn't work this way:

```
{{ $order_id = PaymentInfo::all() }}
```

And this could be your new controller:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $order_id = PaymentInfo::all();

        return View::make('admin.index')->with('order_id', $order_id);
    }

}
```

Also in your view:

```
@foreach ($order_id as $order)
    <td>{{ $order->lastname }}</td>
@endforeach
```

And you don't need all those get() methods in your model, just get rid of them and still `$order->lastname` will work fine.

Just to clarify:

Won't return a bunch of ids, it will return a collection of Payment objects, the full thing, so you better call it:

```
$orders = PaymentInfo::all();
```

I just kept the name you used to make it work for you.

Comment: I made the changes and things definitely are making more sense now but it is giving an error of "no data received, Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". Am I missing something from my model?

Comment: Take a look at your web server logs, you should see some errors there.

Comment: Bingo, that was it. Thanks!